# misc.ip_loadbalancer is not working - POX, mininet

Tags: networking, load-balancing, mininet, pox

I did configuration as follow - just changed the IP addresses:
https://viveksubbarao.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/how-to-setup-a-sdn-using-openvswitch-and-odl-controller/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS0nB.jpg)

All the VMs are in a different LAN Segments (VMware).
When I'm turning on -
*./pox.py --verbose forwarding.l2_learning* it's working as expected I can ping from host to servers but when I'm typing

*./pox.py --verbose misc.ip_loadbalancer --ip=10.0.1.1 --servers=10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2*
But the log info did not show "Server XX up" (https://pox-dev.noxrepo.narkive.com/zTPw06MB/how-to-use-module-misc-ip-loadbalancer - same issue)

output of command on ovs:
b711d1fe-c0b2-4424-a862-dffb0c3757e2
Bridge br0
Controller "tcp:10.0.0.100:6633"
fail_mode: secure
Port ens33
Interface ens33
Port ens37
Interface ens37
Port br0
Interface br0
type: internal
Port ens38
Interface ens38
ovs_version: "2.17.8"

I don't know what to do with this case, do you have any idea? I don't want to do it in mininet.

Just want to use basic load balancer.